# How do you bring a DOQQ into your dataframe

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, united-states

I have a DOQQ aerial photo that is orthorectified.  I would like to bring it into the dataframe to digitize building and streets and create feature layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that ArcMap is able to display the images once you get them in, and it's just that ArcCatalog doesn't recognize the file name extension, you can customize that. see the ["displaying specific raster formats"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000091000000) page in ArcGIS help for the details. It's mostly spelled out there. Once you get to the "Raster File Formats Properties" screen, click "advanced" and you can add a file extension to the list. Or alternatively, you can just edit an existing entry and add an additional file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that DOQQ is in an image format supported by ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 then you should be able to drag and drop it into ArcMap from its Catalog window just like you can for any other supported formats.  It will go into whichever data frame you have active at the time.

I could not find a link to the 10.0 equivalent documentation when I looked just now but it will be very similar to the [10.1 Supported raster dataset file formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000).

Comment: yes I was trying to do that but I cannot get the Arc Catalogue to recognize the image files.  I suppose I can simply add it from the file it resides in through the Add Data Button

Comment: @user30728 Add Data and drag/drop from the Catalog window are just two ways to do the same thing.  If this DOQQ file is not showing up in the Catalog window then you may want to research/ask about its image format separately.